# how to implement the UIPageControl And UISearchBar

Tags: objective-c, ios4

hi i have implemented UIPageControl on top of UIViewController , and i'm trying to implement at the vary left side of the page control a UISearchBar and UITableView

i spend so time on the internet looking for a solution .
what i need to do ??

to put the UISearchBar on UIView or there is something else?

Comment: btw i'm trying to implement a page Control with Search Bar as apple implemented in the main screen

Answer (score 0):

Check out [UISearchDisplayController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UISearchDisplayController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and the related sample code. It won't work right out of the box. Especially if you want to have a black background rather than a table view when you start.

If `UISearchDisplayController` doesn't work you can do use a `UISearchBar` on a `UIView` and respond to the `UISearchBarDelegate` in your controller. By implementing `searchBar:textDidChange:` and showing a custom `UITableView` when text is entered and then hidden or removed when the search field is empty you can provide the desired functionality.